# Stack Overflow while editing profile

Tags: support, profile-page

Sorry, I posted this same topic twice, the first time on stackoverflow.com and then here, but if you have a problem with that, complain to the guy that told me to put it here instead. Anyway, the original question: [Stackoverflow while editing profile info [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325208/stackoverflow-while-editing-profile-info).

---

I was editing my profile on this site and where it says **Career** *Where Do You Code* there is an option that says **Just <3 Code** and in the input textbox beside it, the Placeholder says **Share a favorite project or something you hack at.** and the Textbox title is **Just <3 Code**.

Is it supposed to say that because that is something I never seen before?

Sorry if that this question is not important. I just wanted to know here is a photo of it. I know all of the East Coast United States is getting a DDOS attack on a lot of popular websites/servers example: Facebook, Twitter, PSN, etc. which I am on the East Coast, and I'm not sure if it was hacked or supposed to be like that.

Again sorry this question was not important, but it was just something that was really weird, and it didn't seem normal.

[image: Screenshot of a Careers' page]

Answer (score 1):

It matches the "Where do you code?" question to the left, which you answered as "Just <3 Code".

I know that's been one of the three options for "Where do you code?" for quite a long time, not sure whether it has always appeared in the place you are pointing out.

Comment: o i may have clicked the Just <3 Code option but what about the placeholder in the textbox it says "Share a Favorite Project or something You Hack at?" that I don't remember it saying that.Btw IK that there is a duplicate question which is the one I posted on stackoverflow.com and someone told me to post it on meta.stackoverflow.com so I did so no one blame me for it someone told me to put it here.